# Test if a type is any[] or unknown[]

Tags: typescript

How does one test if a type is strictly `unknown[]` or `any[]`?

Related, but not relevant, these are how I'm testing for other types:

```js
type IsStrictAny<T> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? T : never;
type IsNotStrictAny<T> = T extends IsStrictAny<T> ? never : T
type IsVoid<T> = T extends void ? T : never
type IsStrictVoid<T> = IsVoid<T> & IsNotStrictAny<T>
type IsStrictNever<T> = [T] extends [never] ? true : false
type IsStrictUnknown<T> = T extends IsStrictAny<T> ? never : unknown extends T ? T : never
```

If there are better ways to do this then that would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not extract the item using a conditional type and then use the `IsStrictAny` you already use to detect `any`

```
type IsStrictAnyArray<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ? IsStrictAny<U> : never;

// any
type T1 = IsStrictAnyArray<any[]>
// All are never
type T2 = IsStrictAnyArray<unknown[]>
type T3 = IsStrictAnyArray<void[]>
type T4 = IsStrictAnyArray<undefined[]>
type T5 = IsStrictAnyArray<null[]>
type T6 = IsStrictAnyArray<number[]>
type T7 = IsStrictAnyArray<any>
type T8 = IsStrictAnyArray<never>
type T9 = IsStrictAnyArray<unknown>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgzgZWAJwJYGNgEEB2IA8AKgHxQC8UADFBAB7AQ4AmcUAFAIxQBkUhAlFAD8fKAC4oOCADcIyANwAoUJFhwAcgHtgSNJlwES5UXQbNW8XRmx4ipEVNnJxfZeGjwAaptRM7xwhp6RhYoaR8mYVEJRzk3VUsUa29ffwovCP9eeC0dJP1bEniPRHzgdRk5NKgAbUIAXSCzUJrY5EaRFABXaAkAMwBDABs4CGK1K0wAVRwAaxxNAHccasDTEItSvRtDe0lK5wkuuYXlpo3REUCYg8VxxO2DLGRkAd2A8-MoZ9eCVBw+nIoFM9g9rAZ8CCXG0lIoAPRwqADPDjQhcdJbcF4H5vfDIkA1erEeGIrBDIZI5DQNqogBMxjBBRAOIIx3mSxwhOJKmghAAzAzMUyWfhwr4uaiACyCyY7EXHJgQPr-CBMCU8vgAVhlZSeL1xOC65PV7j4ADYdY9sfqCIaALYAIzkJtUhAA7JascybXi8NzTYQABye4U+tr+10AThDcp9bNOOGJQA)

You can also detect tuples if you check the `length` property.

```
type IsNotTuple<T> = T extends Array<any> ? number extends T['length'] ? T: never : never;
// Tuple detection 
// any
type T10 = IsStrictAnyArray<IsNotTuple<any[]>>
// never
type T11 = IsStrictAnyArray<IsNotTuple<[any]>>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgzgZWAJwJYGNgEEB2IA8AKgHxQC8UADFBAB7AQ4AmcUAFAIxQBkUhAlFAD8fKAC4oOCADcIyANwAoUJFhwAcgHtgSNJlwES5UXQbNW8XRmx4ipEVNnJxfZeGjwAaptRM7xwhp6RhYoaR8mYVEJRzk3VUsUa29ffwovCP9eeC0dJP1bEniPRHzgdRk5NKgAbUIAXSCzUJrY5EaRFABXaAkAMwBDABs4CGK1K0wAVRwAaxxNAHccasDTEItSvRtDe0lK5wkuuYXlpo3REUCYg8VxxO2DLGRkAd2A8-MoZ9eCVBw+nIoFM9g9rAZ8CCXG0lIoAPRwqADPDjQhcdJbcF4H5vfDIkA1erEeGIrBDIZI5DQNqogBMxjBBRAOIIx3mSxwhOJKmghAAzAzMUyWfhwr4uaiACyCyY7EXHJgQPr-CBMCU8vgAVhlZSeL1xOC65PV7j4ADYdY9sfqCIaALYAIzkJtUhAA7JascybXi8NzTYQABye4U+tr+10AThDcp9bNOOGJdw1OW0hC6YCGEFWn1CIvxe3tTuc6y+hBqAHIszgAObAAAWFY6fBuTmhByUCL4GazUEVDEwqE0OCgJKRKI1aOoGNlet++FTwHTmez+K5xK7NMnHHRE111vni+XWfwNXxROJQA)

Comment: Genius solution!  Thanks!

Comment: One weakness in that solution however is that [any] and any[] both pass this test :(

Comment: @TrevTheDev Arrays are base types of tuples. `[1] extends number[]` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGlC8UDaBGAulCAPYEB2AJgM5R4CuAtgEYQBOSGA-FMLWdAFxQBmAhgDZEIQA So this result is not surprising. Excluding tuples is another issue

Comment: Your point is good.  However, it also leaves my original question unanswered as `any[]` is not the same as `[any]` as `any[]` is a superset of `[any]`

Comment: You can detect tuples explicitly via their `length` property. The length will be  a number literal type, while for arrays it will just be a `number`

Comment: @TrevTheDev I added the detection of tuples to the answwer